Is this visualization of the sum of subspaces ok?
I'm self-studying linear algebra and I stumbled upon the following theorem:
" Suppose $V_1,...,V_m$ are subspaces of $V$. Then $V_1+...+V_m$ is the smallest subspace of $V$ containing $V_1,...,V_m$".
I just want to make sure I understood the concept, so I was trying to visualize this in $\mathbb{R}^2$.
So, $\mathbb{R}^2$ is our $V$ and I take arbitrarily 2 subsets of it:

$V_1 \leftarrow \{(a, 3a):a\in \mathbb{R}\}$
$V_2 \leftarrow \{(a, \frac{1}{2}a):a\in \mathbb{R}\}$

Both of them contain $0$, so they should be fine as subspaces.
We can visualize some of the points on these 2 subspaces in the following plot:
VIEW THE PLOT HERE
Now, the sum of the subspaces should be, from what I understood, the set of all the sums of all the elements of $V_1$ with all the elements of $V_2$. All the possible pairs of points, summed and put inside a set. Right?
So I used the points in the previous image to do these sums (just to keep it simple), and I got this:
VIEW THE PLOT HERE
Now. Of course the smallest subset containing both $V_1$ and $V_2$ is $V_1 \cup V_2$, but here we're talking about the smallest subspace containing both $V_1$ and $V_2$, so we're talking about a set where vector addition and scalar multiplication are defined.
I know I probably got wrong a lot of stuff in this post, but what do you think about the visualization? Thanks in advance!

Hint:  $\mathbb R^2$ is two dimensional.  Keep in mind that the "sum" here has got to be an actual subspace.

Ok, maybe I got it. My plot is showing that their sum can span the green region, but actually their sum can span the whole $\mathbb{R}^2$.
